# Symfony 5: How to manipulate session id

Tags: php, session-cookies, symfony5

I have a symfony 5.3 project and my task is to set a prefix to the session id. Not the one saved server-side (in Redis, in this case - I know how to set a prefix there), but the one that is actuall set in the cookie.

I tried this with a string $mySessionId:

```
$this->session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
$this->session->setId($mySessionId);
$this->session->setName('SessionID');
$this->session->start();
```

but that only sets the name, the id is overwritten after the session starts. If I try to set the id after the session->start(), I get the error

```
Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "Cannot change the name of an active session."
```

Sooo... how to use the setId() method? Can the id actually be altered, or will the internal use of session_id() always overwrite my own? If so, what's the point of setId()? Or does the id need to be a different format than my test string, and if it's not, it fails silently? I feel like this should be really easy, and I don't get it.

Comment: Sessions are usually handled by php itself and symfony only exposes it, if you want to change cookie change it there, there is plenty of information on sessions handlers for php out there already. Hope this leads you in right direction.